# Count greater than total number of rows

Tags: mysql, sql

How can `COUNT(*)` in SQL return value that is greater than total number of rows in the table ?

Comment: Maybe show the query ? If there's a `join` or something in it, `count` can very well return a value greater than the total number of rows in the table

Comment: What is the select?  Is it from a single table - if you are linking two tables, for example, then you can end up with more rows easily

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, StackOverflow is neither a forum, tutorial site nor web search replacement. We can help with [certain problems](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), but it's your job to [put some efforts](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) in the first place, including elementary [(re)search](https://www.google.com). Read [stack overflow question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: Why do you think it is so what are you comparing to?

Answer (score 2):

It can. It cannot. We can never tell unless you let us know what is your actual requirement or question more specifically.

I will try to answer it generally.

**It cannot:**
When you are dealing with a single table.

**It can**
When you are dealing with more than one table.

**Logic:**

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM YourTable
```

It gives the number of rows from the table 'YourTable'.  That's it. Knowing this, it is hard to come up with a question like you did.

In case if you are meaning to ask some other question, I would suggest you put it elaborately with some piece of code. It would help in getting you the relevant answers.

Comment: THis is my code SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `table` .But when im checking the no of rows its far lesser by a million

Comment: May be some screenshots will help.